# Simple data thread question - java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

If I have a static array which does not change after being populated.   Multiple threads can read this array at the same time can't they?   I believe problems arise when one thread trys to read the array while another is modifying it.

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't access it with multiple threads while the array is being populated.  If nothing is modifying the data (only reads) then you should be fine.  Your assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe. The first step in static initialization is to synchronize on the class [1]

If all other accesses are read, the program is correctly synchronized.

[1] http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4.2

Comment: There's a key assumption here that the array is being populated in the static initialiser (and that doesn't have anything freaky with threads going on).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly.  Google "critical region" for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple threads accessing the same data at the same moment, you have to use `synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as everything is read-only then you'll be fine. Just make sure that no threads attempt to read *while* the array is being populated (e.g. if it's lazily populated).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, data reads are thread safe - it is only when you are changing the data that you have to be concerned.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mostly reading the array, `ReadWriteLock` will perform better then `synchronized` http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you already have you answer by now thanks to the answers above. Since you are working with multiple threads I will assume that you are working with multiple cores either on the same chip or distributed. In both cases there is something that you can do to improve performance: Let all threads have a copy of data as it is Read only access. This way they can use caches or local memory efficiently and avoid reading over inter-core, interprocessor links. This is obviously impractical if the array is way too big (Bigger than largest cache).